# How to update value in .ini file in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, ini

I have .ini file that i should change the value of a string name "Error" its default value is "no":

this is the .ini file :

```
[Error]
value=no
```

How to update value in .ini file in VB.net ?

Comment: how are you reading it?  INI files are a bit antiquated, so its not clear if you are parsing them manually or using PInvoke

Comment: Why don't you use an XML file for this purpose?

Comment: why i should use XML file i think i can use .ini file ?!

Comment: Dim ini_file As New IniFile(Path & "\userTest.ini")
        Dim iniString = ini_file.GetString("Error", "value", "(none)")
      
        If iniString.Equals("no") Then
          ....
        Else
           ....

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3287991/INI-Files-Will-Never-Die-How-To-in-NET.htm) post outlines a class you can use if you really want to use INI files; I've personally started using XML files for simple configs, though.

```
Public Class IniFile
 ' API functions
 Private Declare Ansi Function GetPrivateProfileString _
   Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA" _
   (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
   ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpDefault As String, _
   ByVal lpReturnedString As System.Text.StringBuilder, _
   ByVal nSize As Integer, ByVal lpFileName As String) _
   As Integer
 Private Declare Ansi Function WritePrivateProfileString _
   Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "WritePrivateProfileStringA" _
   (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
   ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpString As String, _
   ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
 Private Declare Ansi Function GetPrivateProfileInt _
   Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetPrivateProfileIntA" _
   (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
   ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal nDefault As Integer, _
   ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
 Private Declare Ansi Function FlushPrivateProfileString _
   Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "WritePrivateProfileStringA" _
   (ByVal lpApplicationName As Integer, _
   ByVal lpKeyName As Integer, ByVal lpString As Integer, _
   ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
 Dim strFilename As String

 ' Constructor, accepting a filename
 Public Sub New(ByVal Filename As String)
   strFilename = Filename
 End Sub

 ' Read-only filename property
 ReadOnly Property FileName() As String
   Get
       Return strFilename
   End Get
 End Property

 Public Function GetString(ByVal Section As String, _
   ByVal Key As String, ByVal [Default] As String) As String
   ' Returns a string from your INI file
   Dim intCharCount As Integer
   Dim objResult As New System.Text.StringBuilder(256)
   intCharCount = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, _
      [Default], objResult, objResult.Capacity, strFilename)
   If intCharCount > 0 Then GetString = _
      Left(objResult.ToString, intCharCount)
 End Function

 Public Function GetInteger(ByVal Section As String, _
   ByVal Key As String, ByVal [Default] As Integer) As Integer
   ' Returns an integer from your INI file
   Return GetPrivateProfileInt(Section, Key, _
      [Default], strFilename)
 End Function

 Public Function GetBoolean(ByVal Section As String, _
   ByVal Key As String, ByVal [Default] As Boolean) As Boolean
   ' Returns a boolean from your INI file
   Return (GetPrivateProfileInt(Section, Key, _
      CInt([Default]), strFilename) = 1)
 End Function

 Public Sub WriteString(ByVal Section As String, _
   ByVal Key As String, ByVal Value As String)
   ' Writes a string to your INI file
   WritePrivateProfileString(Section, Key, Value, strFilename)
   Flush()
 End Sub

 Public Sub WriteInteger(ByVal Section As String, _
   ByVal Key As String, ByVal Value As Integer)
   ' Writes an integer to your INI file
   WriteString(Section, Key, CStr(Value))
   Flush()
 End Sub

 Public Sub WriteBoolean(ByVal Section As String, _
   ByVal Key As String, ByVal Value As Boolean)
   ' Writes a boolean to your INI file
   WriteString(Section, Key, CStr(CInt(Value)))
   Flush()
 End Sub

 Private Sub Flush()
   ' Stores all the cached changes to your INI file
   FlushPrivateProfileString(0, 0, 0, strFilename)
 End Sub

End Class
```

Usage example:

```
Dim objIniFile As New IniFile("c:\data.ini")
objIniFile.WriteString("Settings", "ClockTime", "12:59")
Dim strData As String = _
    objIniFile.GetString("Settings", "ClockTime", "(none)")
```

Comment: this exemple "writeString " add new string and not update old one !!?

Answer (score 1):

Achrez you can use my library for manipulating with INI files, it's available on GitHub:

https://github.com/MarioZ/MadMilkman.Ini/

Here is how you can use it:

```
Dim ini As New IniFile
ini.Load("path to your INI file")
ini.Sections("Error").Keys("value").Value = "yes"
```

Comment: Thanks Mario. I wonder if you should create a part called "Update" in your help files. This line really helped all the code make more sense.

Comment: This still has to be the easiest option out there. I've used it in 2 projects now, and is becoming my go to... Thanks Mario.